# Navigation Controller button right

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I would like to put a button "Sign out" in the left of the navigation bar in all my views, which would allow the user to sign out whatever he is (I have many screens and I would like to put the *i* button in the right of the navigation bar which allows the user to sign out whatever he is).

Can I do this with one method (signOut...) or should I put a method signOut in each view?

Comment: You mean on the right intially, right?

Comment: I have an application based in navigation controller, the first screen ask the user to sign in, when he does, he can navigate in many screens. i would like to put a button in the right navigation bar for all my screens to allow the user to sign out and go to the first screen ( sign in)

Comment: Alright, look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put a signOut button on the [navigation controller's](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) [navigation bar](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW8) in the class in which you set up the navigation controller. Your signOut method could be placed there as well.

Comment: I hava, UINavigationController *naviController in my app delegate, can i put the methode sign out in my app delegate ?

Comment: Yes why not, no worries there.

Answer (score 0):

I Suggest you Build a User Management Class that holds all user interactions and information and have a Method let's say Signout, When the Application Start up create this object and keep passing it to to the Controllers, like a session Object.